# Foreach ad-user add it's own attribute values

Tags: powershell, foreach, active-directory

I want to create a PowerShell script that adds bulk values to AD attribute `aaccountRoles` according to `sAMAccountName`.

The concept looks like this:

```
sAMAccountName  aaccountRoles
test.user1      value1,value2,value3
test.user2      value1,value2,value3
```

[image: CSV FILE]

```
$data = Import-Csv -Path .\file.csv -Header "sAMAccountName", "aaccountRoles"
foreach($user in $data){ 
    Get-ADUser -Filter "sAMAccountName -eq '$($user.sAMAccountName)'" | ForEach {Set-ADUser -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -Add @{aaccountRoles="$($user.aaccountRoles)"}}
}
```

I have created the above script in PowerShell, but it does not seem to work.

if I save csv file like this:
csv file:[my csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJcfb.png)
the above script **works**, but it adds only the first value for each user, whereas I have to add all values of "aaccountRoles" attribute from csv file

Comment: *" it does not seem to work"* - what does that mean?

Comment: Hello,Sir
By this I mean, it is not working as expected

Comment: *"it is not working as expected"* - what does that mean? Spell out your expectations. Show the actual results, show the expected results. Write down any error messages you get. Don't make people guess.

Comment: it is not even giving an error

Comment: The c in csv is for comma - you need to re-format your csv file

Comment: re-format to what ?
sAMAccountName,aaccountRoles
tes.user1,value1,value2,value3
test.user2,value1,value2,value3

re-format like this u mean?

Comment: Please open your csv in Notepad and show us the first 3 or 4 lines (sensitive data sanitized of course) so we can see if [1] it already has headers and [2] what delimiter character is used to separate the fields. Paste these lines [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70968473/edit) as formatted text, not in a comment. Also, (could be just me), I have never heard of an attribute `aaccountRoles`. Is this a custom attribute you have added to your AD schema? What format does it take? a single comma delimited string or a string **array** ?

Comment: Does ```Import-Csv -Path .\file.c...... -Delimiter "`t"``` work?

Comment: Theo, I have edited my question above, I answer your questions: [1] it has headers [2] to separate them I use ","(comma) delimiter
about "aaccountRoles" attribute, yes this is a custom attribute that we have created in our AD, it takes/accepts both single comma-delimited string and a string array, I can add multiple value in this attribute

Comment: Pick something else to separate the values. Eg. header could be `sAMAccountName,aaccountRoles`, then row could be `test.user1,value1;value2;value3` (then pass `@{aaccountRoles = $user.aaccountRoles.Split(';')}` to `Set-ADUser`)

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, I tried as you have shown but it added all values to one row, but the goal is to add each value to each row

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, thanks bro, your method worked
in the beginning I run the script like this: $($user.aaccountRoles)Split(';'))
when I put as yours, like this: $user.aaccountRoles.Split(';')
it worked, it added each value to each row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Import-Csv` assumes normal comma-separated values. So when it sees this:

```
sAMAccountName  aaccountRoles
```

It assumes that's all one value, since there is no comma separating them. It should look like this:

```
sAMAccountName,aaccountRoles
```

However, you also have commas separating the multiple values of `aaccountRoles`, and you don't want it to recognize those commas as separating new rows. So enclose those entire values in quotes:

```
sAMAccountName,aaccountRoles
test.user1,"value1,value2,value3"
test.user2,"value1,value2,value3"
```

Then when assigning the values, use `@{aaccountRoles = $user.aaccountRoles.Split(',')}`

Comment: thanks for your answer but it adds all values to the first row,
the result: value1,value2,value3
but the goal is to add each value to each row:
value1\n
value2\n
value3\n

Comment: @khamro Based on the other comments, I think you'd have to use `@{aaccountRoles = $user.aaccountRoles.Split(',')}` to split the values.

Comment: Gabriel Luci, yes it worked, thanks bro